# Chrome autofill fills fields but actual value is empty

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome

I have a React component with address input fields. When I use chrome autofill it sets the address fields (they are visibly set to the correct value) however the actual value of the input is still empty. I cannot see the values (e.g. New York City) in the HTML but they are visible. When I click on the fields the cursor is at the start of the input and the values cannot be selected such as putting cursor at the middle of the input. My inputs have an onchange handler which isn't being called. How to capture autofill values?

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: FWIW, for security reasons, the autofill information isn't actually "committed" to the DOM until the user clicks on the browser-native UI to select the entry.

Comment: I was getting the same on Chrome 71.0.3578.98. I updated to 72.0.3626.96 and all now works. I couldn't find any solution before updating.